# change SYMBOL CONST in bitmex API

Tags: php, bots

i am making a trader BOT(with PHP)
and i use [this](https://github.com/kstka/bitmex-api-php) library
in this library you can see SYMBOL const
this is BITCOIN and i need change it in my PHP code(some Times BTC and some Times ETH)
Please help!
`const SYMBOL = 'XBTUSD';`

Comment: you can easily subclass the class and add your own symbols

Comment: or even easier change the source code of the original class and use the modified class instead in your project

Comment: @NikosM. please explain more :)